# Errors "Stray end tag head" and "An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open"

Tags: html, w3c-validation

If I try to do the W3C validation with my site (www.primapaginaonline.it), DOCTYPE HTML5, I get some errors, but there are two that I don't understand.

The first is the error

> Line 110, Column 7: Stray end tag `head`.

and on line 110 there is only

```
</head>
```

The other error is

> Line 111, Column 24: An `body` start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.

And the code of line 111 is

```
<body class="home blog">
```

And after that it says it cannot continue. How can I solve these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you validate your site, you should start from the beginning. Remove earlier errors and then check if the error still exists.

When I modified your code and only:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it-IT" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />


<title>
 Prima Pagina Online  
</title>


</head>
```

was left at the beginning of file, there was no warning about head tag

**EDIT**

I looked at your code and the main problem is that you put Facebook code in head section. You should put it right after opening body tag.

Comment: I tried to disable the facebook code but the errors remains

Comment: Not it, doesn't. I've checked it twice. Just remove everything from `<div id="fb-root"></div>` to `ga('send', 'pageview');</script>` including and you will se there won't be any error connected to `body`. Now in your source you still have facebook code inside head section

Answer (score -1):

In my case, validator output exactly such errors when the site is working on the https protocol, and in the css file includes line with import google font via http protocol

`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com...`

must be replaced by:

`@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com...`